# why can't I display the json with value from restTemplate?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want my program to display name of page and http status code however whenever I try to include the myServicePinger method, page breaks down and displays [image]

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class EndpointsService {
    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    public int myServicePinger() {
        HttpStatus statusCode = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://www.google.com/", String.class).getStatusCode();
        return statusCode.value();
        //log.info(statusCode);
    }
    public List<Endpoints> getEndpoints() {
        myServicePinger();
        int code = myServicePinger();
        return List.of(
            new Endpoints(
                    "google.com",
                    code
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `@Bean` method as that creates a circulair dependency, also how is this method being called? Is there a stacktrace somewhere, if so show it.